# Windows Server 2008 R2 cannot change DNS Domain Context on some machines

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-domain

So I have a small Windows Server 2008 R2 network consisting of a domain controller, a file server, SQL server, etc. All machines are joined to a windows domain (CPUSHIELD.COM) and show up in Active Directory Users and Computers under the Computers OU. Each computer has a DNS record as well that was populated when I joined each computer to the domain.

However, when I go to my SQL server VM (which is joined to CPUSHIELD.COM) and try to add domain users or groups to the local users or groups on my file server (which is a physical machine) or my sql server (which is a virtual machine), for some reason I cannot change the context to the CPUSHIELD.COM domain. For example:

[image: Trying to add a user from the domain to a local security group]
[image: No Domain showing up in search context]

Here is the really strange thing, I have two other servers on my network that do show CPUSHIELD.COM in the *From This Location* field (as I would expect with any machine joined to a domain) and I am able to search the local machine and/or domain for users/groups to add. I have done hundreds of Windows Server 2008 installs, and this is the first time I have run into this issue. Any ideas? Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Membership problems in Active Directory are sometimes solved by dropping the troublesome computer/VM from the domain and joining back in.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that already :(

Comment: See if [KB 2018583](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2018583) or [KB 832223](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832223) ring a bell. Also check the DNS server in Properties of TCP/IPv4.

Comment: When the Domain joined is not shown , it is probably a network problem, make sure that your VM network configuration settings are correct and on the same network range with your domain controller. Can you ping CPUSHIELD.COM from your VM?